# main(String args[]) already defined in class

Tags: java

i have been trying to create a little java program that all it does is allow the user to select a txt file and then to print out the file to a printer,

below is the code : i have tried to compile it but i get the error  main(String args[]) already defined in class, this code was working before i added in the top piece of code that allows the user to select a fie, also will what i am trying to do even work ? all i am trying to do is print to a printer the contents of a txt file then ill be done :)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PrintText implements Printable {


    // Below the code will allow the user to select a file and then print out the contents of the file
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //selects the file
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String filename = file.getName();
        //System.out.println("You have selected: " + filename);  testing to see if file seleected was right
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

        //Reads contents of file into terminal 
        //FileReader fr = new FileReader("filename");
        // FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:/Documents/" + "filename")); 

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
        String mText; 
        while((mText = br.readLine()) != null) { 
            //Displays the contents of the file in terminal
            System.out.println(mText); 
        } 
        //fr.close(); 
         }


        //private static final String mText = 
        //    "This is a test to see if this text will be printed "; //This works perfectly fine

        private static final AttributedString mStyledText = new AttributedString(mText);


    /**
     * Print a single page containing some sample text.
     */
    static public void main(String args[]) {
        /* Get the representation of the current printer and 
         * the current print job.
         */
        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        /* Build a book containing pairs of page painters (Printables)
         * and PageFormats. This example has a single page containing
         * text.
         */
        Book book = new Book();
        book.append(new PrintText(), new PageFormat());
        /* Set the object to be printed (the Book) into the PrinterJob.
         * Doing this before bringing up the print dialog allows the
         * print dialog to correctly display the page range to be printed
         * and to dissallow any print settings not appropriate for the
         * pages to be printed.
         */
        printerJob.setPageable(book);
        /* Show the print dialog to the user. This is an optional step
         * and need not be done if the application wants to perform
         * 'quiet' printing. If the user cancels the print dialog then false
         * is returned. If true is returned we go ahead and print.
         */
        boolean doPrint = printerJob.printDialog();
        if (doPrint) {
            try {
                printerJob.print();
            } catch (PrinterException exception) {
                System.err.println("Printing error: " + exception);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print a page of text.
     */
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int pageIndex) {
        /* We'll assume that Jav2D is available.
         */
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        /* Move the origin from the corner of the Paper to the corner
         * of the imageable area.
         */
        g2d.translate(format.getImageableX(), format.getImageableY());
        /* Set the text color.
         */
        g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
        /* Use a LineBreakMeasurer instance to break our text into
         * lines that fit the imageable area of the page.
         */
        Point2D.Float pen = new Point2D.Float();
        AttributedCharacterIterator charIterator = mStyledText.getIterator();
        LineBreakMeasurer measurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(charIterator, g2d.getFontRenderContext());
        float wrappingWidth = (float) format.getImageableWidth();
        while (measurer.getPosition() < charIterator.getEndIndex()) {
            TextLayout layout = measurer.nextLayout(wrappingWidth);
            pen.y += layout.getAscent();
            float dx = layout.isLeftToRight()? 0 : (wrappingWidth - layout.getAdvance());
            layout.draw(g2d, pen.x + dx, pen.y);
            pen.y += layout.getDescent() + layout.getLeading();
        }
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Below is the renamed version, however i am getting a new error message : cannot find symbol variable mText

and highlighiting this line of code :

```
    private static final AttributedString mStyledText = new AttributedString(mText);
```

improved code :

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PrintText implements Printable {


    // Below the code will allow the user to select a file and then print out the contents of the file
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //selects the file
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String filename = file.getName();
        //System.out.println("You have selected: " + filename);  testing to see if file seleected was right
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

        //Reads contents of file into terminal 
        //FileReader fr = new FileReader("filename");
        // FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:/Documents/" + "filename")); 

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
        String mText; 
        while((mText = br.readLine()) != null) { 
            //Displays the contents of the file in terminal
            System.out.println(mText); 
        } 
        //fr.close(); 
    } 


        //private static final String mText = 
        //    "This is a test to see if this text will be printed "; //This works perfectly fine

        private static final AttributedString mStyledText = new AttributedString(mText);



    /**
     * Print a single page containing some sample text.
     */
    static public void printer(String args[]) {
        /* Get the representation of the current printer and 
         * the current print job.
         */
        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        /* Build a book containing pairs of page painters (Printables)
         * and PageFormats. This example has a single page containing
         * text.
         */
        Book book = new Book();
        book.append(new PrintText(), new PageFormat());
        /* Set the object to be printed (the Book) into the PrinterJob.
         * Doing this before bringing up the print dialog allows the
         * print dialog to correctly display the page range to be printed
         * and to dissallow any print settings not appropriate for the
         * pages to be printed.
         */
        printerJob.setPageable(book);
        /* Show the print dialog to the user. This is an optional step
         * and need not be done if the application wants to perform
         * 'quiet' printing. If the user cancels the print dialog then false
         * is returned. If true is returned we go ahead and print.
         */
        boolean doPrint = printerJob.printDialog();
        if (doPrint) {
            try {
                printerJob.print();
            } catch (PrinterException exception) {
                System.err.println("Printing error: " + exception);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print a page of text.
     */
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int pageIndex) {
        /* We'll assume that Jav2D is available.
         */
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        /* Move the origin from the corner of the Paper to the corner
         * of the imageable area.
         */
        g2d.translate(format.getImageableX(), format.getImageableY());
        /* Set the text color.
         */
        g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
        /* Use a LineBreakMeasurer instance to break our text into
         * lines that fit the imageable area of the page.
         */
        Point2D.Float pen = new Point2D.Float();
        AttributedCharacterIterator charIterator = mStyledText.getIterator();
        LineBreakMeasurer measurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(charIterator, g2d.getFontRenderContext());
        float wrappingWidth = (float) format.getImageableWidth();
        while (measurer.getPosition() < charIterator.getEndIndex()) {
            TextLayout layout = measurer.nextLayout(wrappingWidth);
            pen.y += layout.getAscent();
            float dx = layout.isLeftToRight()? 0 : (wrappingWidth - layout.getAdvance());
            layout.draw(g2d, pen.x + dx, pen.y);
            pen.y += layout.getDescent() + layout.getLeading();
        }
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two main methods defined into your code...

Comment: *"select a txt file and then to print out the file to a printer"* Also see [`Desktop.print(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#print%28java.io.File%29) for a more generic 'one-liner' that should work for text files, images, HTML, Word docs, ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is exactly what it says: you have two `main(String[])` methods. You can only have one method with a given name and signature in each class. So you'll have to fix your code in some way that makes that hold. (I.e. rename one of the methods, for starters.)

Comment: Thanks i have renamed one of my methods, now i am getting a new error,          cannot find symbol variable mText

Answer (score 0):

A main method starts like this:

```
static public void main(String args[]) {
...
...
}
```

The main method is the entry point to your application. You should only have one so that your application knows where to start. 
You currently have of these methods, which is why your application won't run.